# Why PowerMock is attempting to load the server.xml file if the static class is mocked out?

Tags: java, unit-testing, logging, junit, powermock

I am trying to unit test a code that deals with Message Logging which brings in a lot of environmental dependency. This Message Logger is a framework used by all developers across teams. I have used PowerMock for the same since the Logging class is a static class.

**Though the Junit Unit test runs Green after using Power Mock, it is still attempting to load the server.xml file.**

The Class calls are as follows

Unit Test Class calls -> Static Logger Class calls-> Static Environment Class.

This Static Environment Class deals with loading and parsing the server.xml file.

I have tried the following as well but even then its tring to load the xml file:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)

@PrepareForTest({Logger.class,EnvFunctions.class})

PowerMockito.mockStatic(Logger.class);

PowerMockito.mockStatic(EnvFunctions.class);
```

**Do i need to do some extra work for it to no longer attempt to load that file?**

I am tyring to mock a static void class and have tried to use doNothing and supress as well. but its not working out

```
doNothing.when(Logger.class);

suppress(everythingDeclaredIn(Logger.class));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the response.

I was able to solve it with the above explanation

It was attempting to load server.xml file because the Logger.class has a static initializer block which was calling another static method dealing with loading of the xml file.

@SuppressStaticInitializationFor annototation for powermock did the trick

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)

@PrepareForTest({Logger.class})

@SuppressStaticInitializationFor("org.mycompany.Logger")
public Class A{
PowerMockito.mockStatic(Logger.class);
}
```